# How do I save centroids in a shapefile, together with a geometry?

Tags: python, pandas, shapely, geopandas

I calculate a centroid for some `GeoDataFrame`

```
M["centroid"] = M.centroid
```

now, I'd like to save that column in a `shp` file, and do

```
M[["centroid","geometry"]].to_file("mfile.shp")
```

But the driver complains I cannot save a `Point` together with my geometry. I guess that's ok, but I'm wondering what's the best way to store controid information alongside other geo info using `geopandas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because GeoPandas will not allow you to save two geometry columns (when create shapefiles), I would recommend saving xy coordinates into columns for each centroid. From that you can always easily get shapely.Point.

```
for index, row in M.iterrows():
    centroid_coords = row.geometry.centroid.coords.xy
    M.loc[index, 'cen_x'] = centroid_coords[0][0]
    M.loc[index, 'cen_y'] = centroid_coords[1][0]

M[["cen_x", "cen_y", "geometry"]].to_file("mfile.shp")
```

EDIT based on comment below (thanks, didn't realise it):

```
temp = M.centroid

M['cen_x'] = temp.x
M['cen_y'] = temp.y

M[["cen_x", "cen_y", "geometry"]].to_file("mfile.shp")
```

Comment: Small comment: you don't need to iterate, as you can access the x/y coordinates directly: `M.centroid.x` and `M.centroid.y` (or save the `M.centroid` to a temporary variable to avoid calculating it twice)